# Слайдер на jQuery и mousemove, как добавить активные переключения NEXT PREV?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slider, carousel

Всем привет!
Есть во такой скролинг изображений.
У него есть ряд недостатков:

1. Нет индикации какое именно фото отображено сейчас, первое или второе.
2. Нет способа управлять с смартфонов или сенсорного экрана.

Если первый недостаток можно еще простить, то вторая проблема, неплохо так бесит) 
Может ли кто подсказать, как задействовать кнопки "далее" и "назад", что бы дать пользователю с сенсорным экраном, хоть какое право на жизнь.

Возможно у кого то будет альтернативный вариант карусели или слайдера для списка карточек.

Заранее благодарен!

```js
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  
  jQuery(".company-gallery").each(function(){
   jQuery(this).children().children().first().show();
  });
  
  var visibleChild = 1;
  
  jQuery(".company-gallery").mousemove(function( event ) {
   var nrChildren = jQuery(this).children().children().size();
   var offsetX = parseInt(jQuery(this).offset().left);
   var width = parseInt(jQuery(this).width());
   var currentChild = parseInt((event.pageX - offsetX) / (width/nrChildren));
   if((currentChild+1)>=nrChildren){
    currentChild = nrChildren-1;
   }
   if(currentChild!=visibleChild){
    jQuery(this).children().children().hide();
    jQuery(this).children().children().eq(currentChild).show();
    visibleChild = currentChild;
   }
   
  });
    
    });
```

```css
.item-place {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
 }
  
  .col-md-5 {
 width: 500px;
 }
  .company-gallery {
    height: 225px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
 }
  .company-gallery img {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto !important;
    min-width: 100%;
 }
  .btn {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    cursor: pointer;
 background:#eee;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.3;
    border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item-place">
 <div class="col-md-5">
  <div class="company-gallery">
   <a target="_blank" href="#">
    <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-77/data1/images/road220058.jpg" style="display:none">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRhNCxpf7pVvzKAHFEfEOuthXqFx8sAN_O2PVQFhF4p5ltbNPM7" style="display:none">
    <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-11/data/images/krasivyi_korabl_-1024x768.jpg" style="display:none">
   </a>
  </div>
  <span class="btn btn-default prev">Назад</span> 
  <span class="btn btn-default next">Дальше</span> 
 </div>
 </div>
  
  <div class="item-place">
 <div class="col-md-5">
  <div class="company-gallery">
   <a target="_blank" href="#">
    <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-77/data1/images/road220058.jpg" style="display:none">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRhNCxpf7pVvzKAHFEfEOuthXqFx8sAN_O2PVQFhF4p5ltbNPM7" style="display:none">
    <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-11/data/images/krasivyi_korabl_-1024x768.jpg" style="display:none">
   </a>
  </div>
  <span class="btn btn-default prev">Назад</span> 
  <span class="btn btn-default next">Дальше</span> 
 </div>
 </div>
  
  <div class="item-place">
 <div class="col-md-5">
  <div class="company-gallery">
   <a target="_blank" href="#">
    <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-77/data1/images/road220058.jpg" style="display:none">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRhNCxpf7pVvzKAHFEfEOuthXqFx8sAN_O2PVQFhF4p5ltbNPM7" style="display:none">
    <img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-11/data/images/krasivyi_korabl_-1024x768.jpg" style="display:none">
   </a>
  </div>
  <span class="btn btn-default prev">Назад</span> 
  <span class="btn btn-default next">Дальше</span> 
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Не совсем понял, в чём заключается ваша проблема. Попробуйте составить [mcve] и расписать _словами_, что вы хотели бы получить.

Comment: Спасибо за замечание, расписал более подробно.